# How to play shoutcast radios in DeaDBeeF audio player?

Tags: internet-radio, deadbeef

How to open shoutcast radios in Deadbeef?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [this post](http://youtu.be/Rp-5P9NQseA)

Install [OpenWith addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-with/) in Firefox

Go to the addon's preferences and add DeaDBeeF (from usr/share/applications)

then just right click  the internet radio link and open in DeadBeeF

[image]

That will send the link to an empty playlist called 'Default"

[image]

and from there it can be dragged/dropped to a separated playlist to be saved for future use.